# Average at 2 week and 3 week intervals

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

Say I have 4 plots of land, and in each plot I measure temperature, humidity, soil pH, etc on an hourly basis. I can calculate the weekly averages via dplyr

```
 library(dplyr)
 my.dfA = group_by(my.df, plot, weeknumber)
 my.dfB = mutate(my.dfA, mean.temp = mean(temp), mean.pH = mean(pH))
```

How do I take two-week averages, then three-week averages for each plot, etc? I don't want moving averages; i'd like to collapse weeknumber 13 and 14 into a single two week period, then do the same for weeknumber 15 and 16, and so on.

```
# A tibble: 6 × 5
                 Date Temperature  Plot dayofyear weekofyear
               <dttm>       <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
1 2016-04-03 15:24:00        13.0     1        94         14
2 2016-04-03 15:39:00        13.0     1        94         14
3 2016-04-03 15:53:59        13.0     1        94         14
4 2016-04-03 16:09:00        13.5     1        94         14
5 2016-04-03 16:24:00        13.0     1        94         14
6 2016-04-03 16:38:59        13.0     1        94         14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a grouping variable  using `%/%`

```
n <- 2
my.df %>%
     group_by(Plot,  weekGrp = (weekofyear-1)%/% n + 1) %>%
     mutate(mean.temp = mean(Temperature))
```

Changing the value of 'n' to 3 gives 3 adjacent 'weekofyear' grouped together.

NOTE: The 'pH' column was not found in the OP's data in the post.

#### data

```
my.df <- structure(list(Date = c("2016-04-03 15:24:00", "2016-04-03 15:39:00", 
"2016-04-03 15:53:59", "2016-04-03 16:09:00", "2016-04-03 16:24:00", 
"2016-04-03 16:38:59", "2016-04-03 15:24:00", "2016-04-03 15:39:00", 
"2016-04-03 15:53:59", "2016-04-03 16:09:00", "2016-04-03 16:24:00", 
"2016-04-03 16:38:59"), Temperature = c(13, 13, 12, 14.5, 13, 
13, 14, 13, 16, 13.5, 18, 19), Plot = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), dayofyear = c(94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 
94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L), weekofyear = c(13L, 13L, 
13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L)), .Names = c("Date", 
"Temperature", "Plot", "dayofyear", "weekofyear"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. This worked as desired.

From a self-learning perspective, I wonder if the same thing can be achieved with packages that work with dates. #lubridate comes to mind but I suppose I'll have to dig through the materials. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ani  I am not sure about a similar function in lubridate.  But, you could check [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/lubridate.pdf)